# Win32_Product install location of a software using powershell in windows but it is coming null or empty

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, get-wmiobject

I am using the command `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product` in powershell to find the InstallLocation of a software installed in windows. It is showing me no value in it. What is the reason many softwares installed in windows do not have InstallLocation property. How do I get it in powershell?

Comment: can you be a bit more specific? is there a specific app you're looking for?

Comment: please give a specific example of the code you are running AND the result you are getting. ///// as an aside, please look up `Win32_Product is evil` for alternate methods and why to use them. [*grin*]

Comment: The msi is developed by me. I installed it then I simply ran Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product in powershell. I do find my software in the list but the value of InstallLocation object property for it is showing blank or null. Do I have to make specific change in my msi so that its location gets reflected in Win32_Product?

Answer (score 0):

If the results returned by your WMI command does not return your wanted InstallLocation for your wanted app then you might want to check these 2 other options:

`Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | % { Get-ItemProperty $_.PsPath } | Select-Object DisplayName, InstallLocation | Sort-Object Displayname -Descending`

`Get-ChildItem HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | % { Get-ItemProperty $_.PsPath } | Select-Object DisplayName, InstallLocation | Sort-Object Displayname -Descending`

Comment: The first command did return my msi in the list but InstallLocation was blank. The second command did not even return the msi. This msi is newly developed by me.

Answer (score 0):

Fullpath or source will have the path:

```
get-package *whatever*
```

Comment: Big +1 to Get-Package. Didn't know this existed until recently. Also handles really well with uninstalling cmdlet too